# C#: public method{get{} set{}} question

Tags: c#, .net, indexer

I'm not entirely sure if I have all the terminology correct so forgive me if I'm wrong. I was wondering if it would be possible to send an argument(s) to the method. Take the following for example.

```
public item (int index)  
{  
    get { return list[index]; }  
    set { list[index] = value; }  
}
```

I know that as it is, it will error. What I'm asking is if there is some way to get it working. Any suggestions or should I figure out some way around it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
// This returns an instance of type "Foo",
// since I didn't know the type of "list".
// Obviously the return type would need to
// match the type of whatever "list" contains.
public Foo this[int index]
{
    get { return list[index]; }
    set { list[index] = value; }
}
```

This is C#'s [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) syntax and it has some limitations (it's not as flexible as VB.NET's parameterful properties) but it does work for your specific example.

Answer (score 6):

As others have shown, you can turn it into an indexer - which can have multiple parameters, by the way.

What you *can't* do is name an indexer in C#... although you can in VB. So you can't have two indexers, one called `Foo` and the other called `Bar`... you'd need to write properties which returned values which were themselves indexable. It's a bit of a pain, to be honest :(

Comment: +1 To you. I never quite understood this though - in VB the syntax for calling a parameterful property looks just like a method call (which of course it is) so what is the advantage? Just so it would look and act like a method but would have "Property" metadata in the assembly?

Comment: @Andrew You can use assignment syntax with properties: 

Product.Description("en-US") = "Tea"

Comment: Which of course you could do as Product.SetDescription("en-US", "Tea"). The argument against parameterful properties is exactly the same as against properties in general - they're just method calls, you could call them as methods (as in Java) etc.

Comment: That makes sense - I guess the only thing that is strange is that at least C#'s indexers _look_ different which aids in readability if nothing else.  The VB syntax is simply confusing as it is indistinguishable from a method.

Answer (score 5):

This is called indexer property

```
public int this [int index]  
{      
     get { return list[index]; }      
     set { list[index] = value; }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you might be looking for is:

```
public Something this[int index]
{
    get
    {
         return list[index];
    }
    set
    {
         list[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the record, Whilst the other answers are valid, you might also want to consider using the following approach:

```
public IList<Something> items { get; set; }
```

This could then be used as follows:

```
Something item = myFoo.items[1];
```

The other answers would be used in the following, slightly different, way:

```
Something item = myFoo[1];
```

The one you want depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve, which is difficult to determine without seeing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the indexer that has been mentioned several times now, another possibility is to make a custom class with an indexer and return an instance of it as a property.

Example:

```
public class IntList
{
    public IntList(IEnumerable<int> source)
    {
        items = source.ToArray();
        Squares = new SquareList(this);
    }

    private int[] items;

    // The indexer everyone else mentioned
    public int this[int index]
    {
        get { return items[index]; }
        set { items[index] = value; }
    }

    // Other properties might be useful:
    public SquareList Squares { get; private set; }

    public class SquareList
    {
        public SquareList(IntList list)
        {
            this.list = list;
        }

        private IntList list;

        public int this[int index]
        {
            get { return list.items[index] * list.items[index]; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexator for solving this problem

```
public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                int idx = FindParam(name);
                if (idx != -1)
                    return _params[idx].Value;

                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Parameter \"{0}\" not found in this collection", name));
            }
            set 
            { 
                int idx = FindParam(name);
                if (idx != -1)
                    _params[idx].Value = value;
                else
                    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(String.Format("Parameter \"{0}\" not found in this collection", name));
            }
        }
```